# Set channel id for DiscordBot for multiple servers

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

Could someone help me set command to set channel for specific server 
so that it does not interfere with each other? Actually I have this:

```
var testChannel = bot.channels.find(channel => channel.id === "hereMyChannelID");
```

I want to set command which Owner can use to set channel id for his server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can accomplish this task by creating a JSON file to hold the specified channels of each guild. Then, in your command, simply define the channel in the JSON. After that, anywhere else in your code, you can then find the channel specified by a guild owner and interact with it.

Keep in mind, a database would be a better choice due to the speed comparison and much lower risk of corruption. Find the right one for you and your code, and replace this JSON setup with the database.

**`guilds.json` setup:**

```
{
  "guildID": {
    "channel": "channelID"
  }
}
```

**Command code:**

```js
// -- Define these variables outside of the command. --
const guilds = require('./guilds.json');
const fs = require('fs');
// ----------------------------------------------------

const args = message.content.trim().split(/ +/g); // Probably already declared.

try {
  if (message.author.id !== message.guild.ownerID) return await message.channel.send('Access denied.');

  if (!message.mentions.channels.first()) return await message.channel.send('Invalid channel.'); 

  guilds[message.guild.id].channel = message.mentions.channels.first().id;
  fs.writeFileSync('./guilds.json', JSON.stringify(guilds));
  await message.channel.send('Successfully changed channel.');
} catch(err) {
  console.error(err);
}
```

**Somewhere else:**

```js
const guilds = require('./guilds.json');

const channel = client.channels.get(guilds[message.guild.id].channel);

if (channel) {
  channel.send('Found the right one!')
    .catch(console.error);
} else console.error('Invalid or undefined channel.');
```