# Store multiple channel IDs in a JSON file

Tags: javascript, json, discord, discord.js

I am making a bot using Discord.js and it only needs to track messages in a certain channel, which I currently have this hard-coded for testing purposes.

```js
var { channelID } = require(`./config.json`);

bot.on("message", async (message) => {
    const args = message.content.split(/ +/g);
    if (message.channel.id === channelID) {
        // ...
    }
});
```

I would like for it to store multiple IDs in a JSON file and to have a `[p]setchannel` command, that would allow me to add one.

I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56262813/set-channel-id-for-discordbot-for-multiple-servers) guide, with no luck.

Answer (score 0):

What you probably want to do is store an array of IDs so that you can retrieve them later.

You should have a `channelIDs` property in your JSON file set to an empty array. Inside your code you can fetch it like this:

```js
const { channelIDs } = require('./config.json') // Now it's an empty array: []
```

When you want to update this array you should update your local one first, and then you can update the config file: to do that you can use [`fs.writeFileSync()`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_writefilesync_file_data_options) in combination with [`JSON.stringify()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify).

```js
const fs = require('fs')

function addChannelID(id) {
  channelIDs.push(id) // Push the new ID to the array

  let newConfigObj = { // Create the new object...
    ...require('./config.json'), // ...by taking all the current values...
    channelIDs // ...and updating channelIDs
  }

  // Create the new string for the file so that it's not too difficult to read
  let newFileString = JSON.stringify(newConfigObj, null, 2) 

  fs.writeFileSync('./config.json', newFileString) // Update the file
}
```

Once you set this function you can add a new ID every time you want, just by calling `addChannelID('channel_id')`.
To check whether the channel the message is coming from should be considered you can use this:

```js
if (channelIDs.includes(message.channel.id)) {
  // OK
}
```

Comment: OK,

I believe I added that correctly. 

So, in my command to add a channel, do I just put `addChannelID('channel_id')`.

Assuming that is correct, when running the code I get:

TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined

Comment: Well, you have to replace `'channel_id'` with the actual ID of the channel, which would be something like `message.channel.id`. Also, you have to make sure that `channelIDs` is declared correctly in the file you're using it, and that your JSON file has a corresponding property set to an empty array