# How to set channel ID for multiple discord servers in python

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm wondering how to send a message to a specific channel in discord.
Here's the code I have so far:

```
import discord

client = discord.Client()


@client.event
async def on_ready():
    channel = client.get_channel(channelID)
    await channel.send('hello')

client.run("---")
```

I want to have is so you run a command like `!channel`, and for that specific guild, the channel ID is set under the `channelID` variable. It has to be like this because if there are multiple servers, the admins can set where the message is sent.

So far, I found this post, but it's for javascript: [Set channel id for DiscordBot for multiple servers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56262813/set-channel-id-for-discordbot-for-multiple-servers)

Here's the updated code:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='$')
client = discord.Client()
main_channels = {}


@bot.command()
async def channel(ctx):
    guild_id = ctx.guild.id
    channel_id = ctx.channel.id
    main_channels[guild_id] = channel_id
    await channel.send('hi')

client.run("TOKEN")
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command you're trying to implement is very simple; just create a dictionary that associates the guild's ID with the ID of the channel in which to send the message:

```
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix = "$")

main_channels = {}

# The following command associates the ID of the guild to that of the channel in which this command is run.
@client.command()
async def channel(ctx):
    guild_id = ctx.guild.id
    channel_id = ctx.channel.id
    main_channels[guild_id] = channel_id

# The following command sends a greeting message to the main channel set earlier for this guild.
@client.command()
async def greet(ctx):
    guild_id = ctx.guild.id
    channel_id = main_channels[guild_id]
    channel = ctx.guild.get_channel(channel_id)
    await channel.send("hi")

bot.run(token)
```

However, I suggest you consider using a permanent data archive, either an offline file (such as a json) or a real database, because once the bot is disconnected it is no longer possible to retrieve the data stored in that dictionary.

Comment: Thank you! Would I need to define the command prefix, like `bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='$')`? What command would the user use to choose the channel?

Comment: You're welcome! Yes, you need to specify the prefix only when you create the ’bot’ instance. Then the command statement would be the prefix followed by the name of the function defined as a command. So if your prefix is ’!’ you would run the command in my code by sending ’!channel’

Comment: Okay. I added changed it to `@bot.command()` at the top and added `await channel.send('hi')` at the bottom. The message never sent to this channel. Am I doing this right?

Comment: Can you edit your question with the updated code? Just to see clearly where the problem lies.

Comment: Yeah. It's at the bottom of the first post.

Comment: Ok, I've edited my code as well. First off you should run a command $channel in the channel that you'd like to set as the main channel. Then you can run $greet and no matter where you send this command, the bot will answer in the main channel set earlier.

Comment: Also, you should get rid of client and run the bot object instead. If something is still not clear move the discussion to the chat just to not stack messages in the comments.

Comment: *Oh my gosh* it worked! Thank you so much for your help! It's exactly what I wanted! I can move this to the chat instead of comments, but what would I use to send it to all guilds?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to send the message to a specific channel, you have to do this:

```
import discord

client = discord.Client()


@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Online')


@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content == "!channel":
        channel = client.get_channel(SPECIFIC CHANNEL ID)
        await channel.send("Hello")

client.run('TOKEN')
```

Else, if you want your bot to response in the same channel as the message, you can do this:

```
import discord

client = discord.Client()


@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print('Online')


@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content == "!channel":
        await message.channel.send("Hello")

client.run('TOKEN')
```

Comment: That makes sense, but this won't work across multiple servers, right?

Comment: The first one not, because it is channel specific. But the second one woll